# Xamarin IOS - 'An unhandled exception occured' during start

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm working on a Xamarin IOS project. And after I updated it to the latest version, suddenly receive this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred.
```

When I try to run it in debug mode.

It doesn't give me anything else, not even the slightest clue. So I have no idea why it breaks. Has anyone else stumbled onto this problem?

Comment: Wow those are the most annoying ones! Assume you've tried the usual clean / rebuild / restart stuff?

Comment: I have tried "everything"! Or I really hope I havent, because I cannot find a solution.

Comment: @DiamondFox , Have you had the same problem?

Comment: Did you tried the following?
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c56b63ed-c603-4368-b78f-cc5c5a36ec02/how-to-break-on-all-errors?forum=vbide

Maybe this will give you additional details about the exception.

Comment: Have you switched "Break on all Errors" on Debug -> Exceptions -> Common Language Runtime exceptions = TRUE. Sometimes the actual error is caught and swallowed

Comment: Hi Pat. Yes, I have tried to switch it on, with no luck. Right now, I have no idea what to do.

Comment: The only thing that I remember doing, was updating Xamarin - the day after , it stopped working. But as other Xamarin project works, it cannot be the update itself.  I have tried to remove the bin folders, and the .suo file.

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/58002/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-catch-all-unhandled-exceptions-on-xamarin-forms

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
```

Comment: Please post only in english